# WebAPI Parameter null

Tags: c#, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I have created a "Person" ADO.Net Entity Model, and "scaffolded" a Web API controller from it. The Entity model is nested, in that in contains an array of other objects.

Because these nested objects contain a property that reference their parent, they are not serializable. So I created a "JSON_Person" class that I could copy the Person object and its nested properties into (minus the nested objects' reference to their parents) so that they could be retrieved with the GET method.

Up until this point, everything worked as expected. I could do a GET request to the API and get an array of JSON objects, each with their own array of nested objects. I could also do a PUT request to the API and update a record.

Even though the PUT method accepts a "Person" object and not a "JSON_Person", it works because (I assume) the JSON_Person and Person's properties match up 1 to 1.

However, after changing the parameter type from Person to JSON_Person, the parameter in the API now always shows null.

I've been told that it's probably a "type conversion fail" but it seems unlikely to me since even if GET the object and then PUT it right back unchanged, it still fails.

Things I've tried:

1. Adding [FromBody] to the API parameter.
2. Changing the "contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'" in the jQuery.ajax call.
3. Setting all properties to null before sending to test type conversion.

---

**AJAX Call**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    url: "/api/person/" + selected.Id,
    data: JSON.stringify(selected),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function() {},
    error: function() {
        return alert("error");
    }
});
```

---

**Put Method**

```
[ResponseType(typeof(void))]
public IHttpActionResult PutPerson(int id, JSON_Person json_Person)
{
    // Convert JSON_Person back to Person and do other stuffs...
}
```

Comment: Have you checked `ModelState.Errors` property?

Comment: I'm not seeing an Errors property for ModelState.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it wasn't a problem with the PUT method at all. I had created a partial class Person to add a constructor to the class that accepted a JSON_Person (to help convert a JSON_Person back into a Person) but didn't have a blank constructor.

After adding a constructor that takes no parameters, it worked!

```
public JSON_Person() { }
```